# Create a pushbutton after clicking one button

Tags: c++, qt, parent-child, qpushbutton

I have created a pushButton " + add ". What I wanna do is creating another pushButton "Edit" after clicking on the "+add" Button, in the same Window.

### How can I edit the text and position of the new "Edit" button ?

Is it possible to create another button in another window ?
I tried to use this method but it doesn t work , I can t understand what should I exactly write as a second parameter ?

```
QPushButton::QPushButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent = nullptr)
```

Comment: Of course it is possible to create a new button. But wouldn't it be easier to create that button beforehand and make it invisible and than just make it visible if you need to?

Comment: Yes, Qt windows can be built dynamically run-time. Second parameter must be a pointer to parent. Typically it is widget or window in what that button must be. Qt has good documentation and  huge pile of examples. Attempt of learning it by trial and error is therefore painful and counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Create all components at the start of the application, then you show and hide them on demand.
2. Only declare references with no initialization, then call creation functions and pass this button reference to it.

The most important part is **NOT** to create a reference inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do that:

```
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Click Me", this); //this is parent, give another window/widget address to draw/create it there
btn->setGeometry(100, 200, 150, 50); //set position, width, height
connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(a_slot())); //make it useful
btn->show();
btn->setText("Push Me"); //change button text later if you want
```